# jQuery ajaxForm plugin not running success function in IE6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I'm using the jQuery plugin [ajaxForm](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) to submit a file upload form via AJAX.  The script submits the form, which, upon success, runs `uploadResponse()` that adds a new row into a `<table>` on the page.  It works fine in Opera, Firefox, Safari, IE7, and IE8.

However, IE6 does not run the `uploadResponse()` after the form has been submitted.  The POST request from the script runs and you can see the file when you refresh the page.  However, `uploadResponse()` simply does not run and the DOM is not updated.

Here is the portion of the script:

```
/**
 * Ajaxified upload form
 */
$('form#upload').ajaxForm(
{
    url: 'ajax/upload.php',
    success: uploadResponse,
    dataType: 'xml'
});

/**
 * Upload form response
 *
 * @param responseXML Returned from the AJAX POST
 */
function uploadResponse(responseXML)
{
    var displayName = $('display_name', responseXML).text();
    var fileName = $('name', responseXML).text();
    var directoryID = $('directory_id', responseXML).text();
    var abbrTitle = $('abbr_title', responseXML).text();
    var tableRow = 'file_' + tableRowCount;

    $('table#listing tbody').prepend(row(displayName, null, '', 'delete.php?directory_id=' + directoryID + '&file=' + fileName, 'Delete', null, tableRow, 'fileName jsHide', 'rename jsHide', 'delete jsHide', abbrTitle));
    $('td.jsHide').fadeIn();

    // AJAX renaming
    $('tr#file_' + tableRowCount).find('td.fileName').click(generateRenameForm);

    // Remove "no files" notficiation
    $('p#noFiles').remove();

    alternatingRows();
    tableRowCount++;
}
```

The particular code in the `uploadResponse()` function is not under question.  It simply does not run (I tested it using `alert()`).

Also, IE6 displays the "this page contains secure and non-secure content" dialogue box.  All of the scripts, stylesheets, etc. are all local on the secure server, so nothing as far as I'm aware is non-secure.  I've checked over this pretty thorougly.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatype:xml is the issue. I'm not sure where I learnt this trick (all credit to that original source). This is how this problem can most likely be solved:

replace "datatype:xml" with

```
datatype: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml"
```

and before you start using the xml response you would need to do this:

```
function parseXMLResult(result) {
    var xmlDoc;
    if (typeof result == 'string') {
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async = "false";
        xmlDoc.loadXML(result);
    } else {
        xmlDoc = result;
    }
    return xmlDoc;

}
```

Hopefully this should solve your problem.

Reg the secure/in-secure warning, you definitely have at least one element might be an image/css/js file which is loading over http. This problem is not specific to IE6 you should see the certificate symbol in the address bar of FireFox to have a red "i" indicating there are issues in the page.
Use a tool like [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) to figure out the offending element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested it in another pc? Maybe is a security setting in your IE6.

Comment: No, but it is a default XP installation, so even if the default security settings don't work, the problem still persists.